# Style the last element of dropdown menu React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I would like to style the last element of the dropdown menu in React native.

I'm using a lib called React native dropdown picker.

It has a prop called itemStyle where you can pass a style for items.

```
item: {
    height: 35,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingLeft: 5,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#000',
  },
```

[The elements style in dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35XG9.png)

So I would like to chnage the borderBottomWidth from 1px to 0 just for the last element.

I don't know if it is possible.

Sorry, If my english is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a prop **renderSeperator** in this library as mentioned in this [pull request](https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker/pull/138) but it's not documented in Readme.

So try this

```
<DropDownPicker
....
renderSeperator={() => <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#000', height: 1 }}>}
/>
```

and remove this part from current itemStyle

```
borderBottomWidth: 1,
borderBottomColor: '#000',
```

Comment: I added but didn't work out.

itemStyle={styles.item}

item: {
    height: 35,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingLeft: 5,
  },

renderSeperator={() => (
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 2 }} />
        )}

Comment: You're using [this](https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker) library right?